# scikit-image - Missing DLL

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have installed scikit-image from a binary but when I run this command:

```
from skimage.measure import structural_similarity
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._regionprops import regionprops, perimeter
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_regionprops.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _moments
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_moments.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import _moments_cy
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

There is a file named _moments_cy.pyd in that directory, not sure if that's what it's asking for.

Comment: Install [numpy+mkl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

Comment: That worked for me on Python 2.7, yet on Python 3.5 the problem persists, although I tried to uninstall and reinstall numpy+mkl again

Answer (score 0):

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
```

The module is now moved to metrics instead of measure.